# How can I add a new drive to an existent logical volume?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

I have a personal remote server running Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 with no graphical access.  I have LVM set up with the internal hard drive (/dev/sda), and I've plugged in a new USB hard drive (/dev/sdb).  I want to add sdb to the VG and LV that I already have so I can use them as one volume.  How can I do that?  I see lots of guides talking about how to create VGs and LVs, but I don't want to create another, I want to add a PV to an existing VG and LV.

```
root@hostname:/# pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda1
VG Name               discus
PV Size               149.05 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              38156
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          38156
PV UUID               lAPqYK-iKju-w7Rz-aMw1-7kee-XGpV-2yin93

"/dev/sdb1" is a new physical volume of "111.79 GiB"
--- NEW Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb1
VG Name
PV Size               111.79 GiB
Allocatable           NO
PE Size               0
Total PE              0
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          0
PV UUID               3bCUBE-9rXt-AAj8-gxGn-jhDD-PtmU-DlPQeA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo vgextend discus /dev/sdb1
```

For LVM questions, see http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: Thanks. That's not an incredibly full answer, but it pushed me in the right direction, and I figure out the rest.