# Increase space in var mount point

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

My `/var` lvm space is full. I have 500 GB space in `/dev/sdb` filesystem which is already mounted to `/mnt/data` point and it has data in it.

I want to move some space from `/dev/sdb` to `/var` lvm without destroying already present data in `/mnt/data`.

[image: lsblk Screenshot]

[image: df -h screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `/var` is an LVM logical volume, you could increase its size by using another disk’s space. However, you are using `/dev/sdb` as an unpartitioned disk. You should:

1. Back up the data from `/dev/sdb` somewhere,
2. partition your `/dev/sdb` drive,
3. restore the original data to one partition and mount it as `/mnt/data` and
4. use another partition as a physical volume which your logical volume `/var` can utilize.

Alternatively, you can make `/mnt/data` a logical volume, too. In this case, the physical volume on `/dev/sdb` could be either a partition or the whole unpartitioned disk. I’d still prefer to create a partition there, even a single one. The partition table does not take much space and the drive will have a more flexible setup – you can see the difference right now.

### See also

- [How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)
- [How can I add a new drive to an existent logical volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485663/how-can-i-add-a-new-drive-to-an-existent-logical-volume)